# tkinter insert autoincrement id and timestamp into database

Tags: mysql, tkinter

there is id autoincrement and datetime timestamp in database, when i try to insert i get error column count doesn't match value count at row 1, how can i fix this ?

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`mobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

def saveData():
if entryName.get() == "" or surname.get() == "":
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "fields are empty")
else:
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", username="admin", password="12345", database="english")
    my_cursor = con.cursor()
    my_cursor.execute("insert into employees values(%s,%s,%s)", (name.get(), surname.get(), mobile.get()))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    viewdata()
    messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Record has been inserted')
```

Comment: Try passing NULL to both columns, `"insert ... values (NULL, %s, %s, %s, NULL)"`.

Comment: @acw1668, doesn't work, and together with null what to specify in the entry parameters `(name.get(), surname.get(), mobile.get())` ?

Comment: 'If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list,' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: @P.Salmon, in the same c#, you can not specify the id autoincrement  and timestamp fields when inserting

Comment: That's not what the manual says..the statement should be insert into employees(name,surname,mobile) values(%s,%s,%s)", (name.get(), surname.get(), mobile.get()))

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes it works, i made a syntax error, thanks you !

Comment: @mark You don't need to change the entry parameters since `NULL` is the value used explicitly inside the SQL statement.  It works for me based on your table definition.

Comment: @acw1668, yes, I understand, my mistake was in mysql syntax, I was looking for the cause of the error elsewhere, Thakns you very much !